# Magento 1.7: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object

Tags: magento

```
<?php Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('children_count','0'); ?>
```

produces:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816
```

what am I missing?

I'm deploying the code on sample data unmodified 1.7 installation

Comment: Are you writing a custom module, or where is it that you are noticing this issue?

Comment: I'm writing a custom module but you can put this code wherever in the template and you ought to get the same error - I'm deploying the code on sample data unmodified 1.7 installation

Comment: it seems magento goes to eav_attribute to look for children_count, can't find it, breaks..

Comment: admin panel is working fine on your installation ?

Comment: It works fine on default (no sample data) installation. it's possible that it produces a bug on sample data installation only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing both sample data Magento and basic Magento, it seems that this code produces error only on sample data version, if flat category is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I would give another way to answer to your question.

The issue because of there is no product attribute `children_count`, it could be your specific attribute that does not exists in your sample magento site.

To develop that part is better to check first if the attribute is exists before add filter to prevent that the code will work in most magento site.

Check if attribute exists:

```html
 /**
  * Check if attribute exists before add it to product filter
  */
 private function _checkIfAttributeExists ($attribCode) {
  $entity = 'catalog_product';
  $attr = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/eav_attribute')
     ->loadByCode($entity, $attribCode);
  
  if ($attr->getId()) {
      return true;
  }
  
  return false;
 }
```

This way you can eliminate the fetal error:

```
if ($this->_checkIfAttributeExists('children_count')) {
   Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('children_count','0');
}
```

This might help others.